# Is there any splash screen module like react-native-splash-screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, splash-screen

I would like to know: Is there any splash screen module like `react-native-splash-screen`? This module helps to hide splash screen via `react-native`. Is there any alternative flutter module to hide splash screen from Flutter?

https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that great idea? Intro Views only run when the first-time app start but splash screen run each time app start.

I found a similar package for Flutter. this package can hide from Flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_splash_screen